# Is it possible to write to any memory address in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

In C++, I want to create a program which can access and write to any physical memory address regardless of what that address is being used by, including Windows kernel mode programs. Is it possible to create such a program that can write to any memory address, such as 0x00, without Windows OS memory permission constraints? Obviously the program cannot be a usermode program, so will I be able to do this if I elevate the program to administrator? Or will I need to write a driver?

Comment: What do you mean by "memory address"? Process-specific virtual address, system-wide virtual address, or physical memory address?

Comment: Physical memory address

Comment: A device driver may write to a physical memory address. But note that a physical memory page may be dumped to a paging file and vice versa, and usually physical memory pages are not bound to specific applications/drivers.

Comment: Incidentally, a user-mode program run as administrator is still a user-mode program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write a driver.  Regular programs, even if running as administrator, cannot write into arbitrary memory addresses.  In fact they can't even access arbitrary physical addresses.

Comment: Can a driver in kernel mode overwrite the physical memory of other kernel mode programs critical to Windows?

Comment: Yes, if you manage to get into kernel mode you can hose the system any way you like.